# How do I fix my finder issues in Mac Big Sur?

Tags: finder, macos-big-sur

I recently updated from Catalina to Big Sur in my MacBook Air 2017. From then I had major issue with finder. I couldn't load a text, pdf, word or excel file. I found that it was due to problems with Finder.

I tried removing the finder.plist file and restarted. It worked fine but when I shutdown the system and power on next day, the above issue comes back.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

Is there a permanent fix for this issue?

I don't know when there will be a security update for my MacBook model and my work can't wait for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case, the cause of this problem is very stupid. My girlfriends has put six thousands of screenshots in desktop when she is watching videos. I even don't notice this until tried deleting *.plist and restart. Just put those screenshots inside one folder solved it. Hope this somehow help. I'm guessing finder is working to hard to maintain thumbnails and arrange the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the old mentioned methods in question for few days without shutting down the system. Later MacOS got updated and get rid of the problem.

Thank you for Your support

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the MacOS may fix the issue.

Another quick solution can be scheduling the rm command to run every day.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and temporary solution, not necessarily a good fix.
This will run the command you supplied in your question every ten minutes:

Run `crontab -e` in the terminal and type

```
*/10 * * * * rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

After exiting the editor the crontab should automatically install and you're set! When you want to remove it later you can just enter that same file and delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Warning - This solution leaves your filesystem unprotected from potentially malicious code, only proceed if you know what you're doing

I've had all kinds of problems with Finder/Filesystem ever since I upgraded to Big Sur. Applications hung/crashing when needing to access the filesystem, Finder crashing consistently on use. Luckily I was able to determine that this was being caused by the system not having appropriate disk access permissions. Apple seriously messed up the system permissions on this update.

Following the guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection), I restarted my Mac in Recovery Mode and disabled the System Integrity Protection (SIP), giving unrestricted access to my Applications to my filesystem. After doing this my Finder and related Apps worked like a charm!

TLDR:

Restart your mac in recovery mode, open the terminal and run:

```
csrutil disable
```